# How do I use nth child in table to color certain column and row of data only?

Tags: css

I am just a Analyst with beginner knowledge of CSS/HTML.

I would like to achieve a simple automatic color changing inside a table. I have did some simple research and this can be achieve using nth child in CSS.

**My objective:**

To color the td `A` (excluding the header) and also to cater for both rowspan or a single td (non rowspan)

["A" should be colored, the rest remain black color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1P9X.png)

Below is the code that I am working with, but as you can see in screenshot, the 2nd row  is also colored which is incorrect:

```
#promotion-popup table td:nth-child(1)
{
color:red
}

<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:705px">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#4472c4; height:55px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:232px"><span style="font-size:8px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>PROMOTION</strong></span></span></td>
        <td style="background-color:#4472c4; height:55px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:243px"><span style="font-size:8px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>REQUIREMENTS</strong></span></span></td>
        
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="height:20px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:232px">
        <p><span style="font-size:8px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>A</strong></span></span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:20px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:243px">
        <p><span style="font-size:8px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>B</strong></span></span></p>
        </td>
        
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:20px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:243px">
        <p><span style="font-size:8px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>B</strong></span></span></p>
        </td>
        
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[wrong outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiYGY.png)

Comment: Could you put your code into the question so we can see what your structure is and also your relevant CSS. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear @AHaworth, I've provided my css in my post.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear perhaps, I need to see the HTML structure too because as it stands I can't see any reason for its not working.

Comment: @AHaworth Hi thanks for the reply, I've updated the post with the table structure too... Hopefully that is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of using the `rowspan`. Have a look at the example here

[image: Example]

**Table 1** is a normal table when we create without using `rowspan`.

Now look at **Table 2** When you use `rowspan` The table structure becomes like this. Using `rowspan` doesnot means that It will swap the next row. rather it pushes the **First column of second Row** to **Second Column of Second Row**. so As of styles applied. you see the second column of second row as red.

**Solution**
The simple solution is as follows

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="display:none"></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result
[image: result]

Hope, This will help you. Please checkmark the asnwer if it solves your problem.

Any queries are welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: #promotion-popup table tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(1)
{
 color:#122342 !important;
}

So in conclusion, I can use the code above in conjunction with your solution to achieve my outcome right?

Comment: yes, and one more thing! As of my experience workig with UI/UX, using nth-child twice may not work. Please check it. Referring to this part of code `table tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(1)`